# Convex hull of finite set in $\mathbb{R^2}$ is a polygon

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, analytic-geometry, combinatorial-geometry, convex-hulls

How can I prove that a convex hull of a finite set of points in the plane is always a convex polygon? This result looks very intuitive, but how can you prove it formally? I thought about taking any convex polygon that contains in it all of the points, and then make it smaller and smaller until one of it's sides meets one of the points, and then do the same to the other sides, but how do you make it formal?

Comment: It depends on your definitions. How do you define "convex hull" and "convex polygon"?

Comment: @lhf Convex hull of a set $S$ is the smallest convex set that contains all of the points in $S$ (which is also the intersection of all convex sets containing $S$). Convex polygon is a simple polygon which is convex as a subset of $R^2$.

Comment: This algorithm gives a proof: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Denote by $S_n = \{p_1, \dots, p_n\}$ the finite set of points and $\overline{S_n} = \mathrm{Conv}(S_n)$.

Let $\mathcal M = \{M \subseteq S_n \mid \mathrm{Conv}(M) = \mathrm{Conv}(S_n)\}$ and $P$ an element of $\mathcal M$ with the minimum cardinal.

Prove that $P$ is a polygon when ordering its points in an appropriate way, i.e rotation around a point in $\mathrm{Conv}(P)$.

Comment: I already thought about removing points which are unnecessary. It did not lead me much far. Can you be more specific on how to prove that this is indeed a polygon?

Comment: It is a simple polygon as the lines joining the vertices can't cross themselves: if not the rotation around a point won't be monotonous. It is convex as it convex hull is... convex.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S\subset\Bbb{R}^2$ finite and $C$ the convex hull of $S$. Because $C$ is convex and contains $S$, it also contains every line segment connecting pairs of points in $S$. It follows that $C$ contains every polygon with its vertices in $S$.

Let $P$ be the union of all polygons with vertices in $S$, so that $S\subset P\subset C$. Note that $P$ is itself a polygon because $S$ is finite. Then $P$ is itself convex because it contains every polygon on its vertices. It follows that $C\subset P$ and hence $C=P$, so the convex hull is a polygon.

Comment: It is not clear to me that $P$ is a polygon. Why is that?

Comment: @Omer It is the union of finitely many polygons; there are only finitely many polygons with their vertices in $S$ because $S$ is finite.

Comment: But why is the union of finitely many polygons is a polygon? If we take two disjoint triangles for example, isn't it a counterexample? And even if it is a polygon, why will the vertices still be elements of S?

Comment: I guess it depends on what you are willing to call a polygon. It's not hard to see that $P$ is connected however, because it contains *every* polygon with its vertices in $S$. So in the case of your two disjoint triangles, you should also include the hexagon(s) on these six vertices in the union.

Comment: As for the vertices; this remark was redundant so I have removed it.

Comment: But now we return to my first question about proving that P is a polygon, don't we? If we agreed that the union of two random polygons might not be one, then to show that P is indeed a polygon, we need to use a different argument, and its still not 100% clear to me, but kind of intuitive though. Moreover I do believe that if indeed P=C then P must have vertices in S, because as far as I know the convex hull of a finite set is a polygon with vertices in that set

Comment: But the point is that we're not taking the union of random polygons. We're taking the union of *all* polygons with their vertices in some fixed finite set $S$. I'm not sure what your definition of a polygon is, but surely a finite union of polygons is again a polygon if it is connected?

Comment: I understand that, but I can't understand how do you justify that it is still a polygon. As we agreed for random polygons it is incorrect, but why for the union of polygons with vertices in a fixed set that will be true?

Comment: Please provide your definition of a polygon, I can't imagine how to make things clearer otherwise.

Comment: When saying polygon I mean simple polygon, as defined in the first line of the wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_polygon